# VHDL how to use a std_logic_vector as index for an array

Tags: vector, vhdl, fpga

I want to use std_logic_vector as index for an array, for example:

```
Data: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal counter : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

output <= Data(counter);
```

Since VHDL syntax check tells me that I should use an integer with Data as index, I want to ask if it's possible to use an std_logic_vector as index.

In case not, if I use a counter like this:

```
signal counter : integer range 0 to 7 := 7;
```

Synthesizer will create a 8 bit counter(because 7 is maximum value) or it will create a 32bit counter? I ask this question becouse if I assign a value of 8 to counter vhdl syntax check doesn't tell me that is an error.

Comment: Synthesizer don't enforce VHDL standard (unlike a good simulator like ModelSim). Assigning 8 to a `range 0 to 7` is illegal by VHDL standard. A synthesizer might accept it (and probably assign 0), but you really shouldn't rely on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use std_logic_vector, you have to convert it:

```
Data: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal counter : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

output <= Data(to_integer(unsigned(counter)));
```

Regarding your second question, this will be a 3 bit counter:

```
signal counter : integer range 0 to 7 := 7;
```

Physically, integer and std_logic_vector makes no difference. It will result in exactly the same hardware after synthesis.
Use the data type that makes most sense in your code.